# Knockout Validation not working the way I want

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

So I am using [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) to validate form input but I am having an issue.

So this is an example from the view model:

```
self.firstName = ko.observable('').extend(
  {
    required: {
      params: true,
      message: 'First Name Required',
    }
  }
);

...

self.errorMessages = ko.validation.group(self);
```

In the View I have:

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: firstName">
    <label for="first-name" class="control-label col-sm-3">
        <span class="text-warning">*</span> First Name
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" name="first-name" type="text" data-bind="value: firstName"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I load the widget, the form shows all the validation errors, such as "First Name Required" long before I hit the submit button.

Is there something specific I have to do to get validation errors to show only AFTER I hit submit on a form?

Answer (score 0):

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5424/, they don't have the `validationElement` binding present in the HTML, and the form do validate when it's submitted.